# Magento 2: Updated file not working

Tags: magento2, class, methods, folder

I want to update the `class Select` and its `getValuesHTML()` method which is saved here: `module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php`

I have made a copy of this file and placed it in my theme here:
`VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php`

I've done the following, but my changes still aren't taking effect:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Have I placed the file in the wrong folder location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overwrite .php files using theme, you have to create new module in app/code/Vendor/Module, and create an etc/di.xml file inside this module.

This should be inside di.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select should extend Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select

or using plugin http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I don't seem to have a folder named `code` in my `app` folder, just `design` and `etc`?

Comment: Then you need to create it :)

Comment: Hi, I've tried to update the class as per your instructions but have come up against some issues. Would you mind having a look here:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112542/magento-2-new-module-causing-crash