# Magento 2: New module causing crash

Tags: magento2, module, class, dependency-injection

I'm trying to override the `module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php` class with a new version which includes a few other bits of custom php. I have done the below and then run the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php cache:clean` commands but the product page is showing a blank/white page.

I created a 'code' folder and placed it here:

`/app/code/`

I created a Vendor folder titled 'Mike' and placed it here:

`/app/code/Mike/`

Within the new `Mike` vendor folder, I created an `etc` folder: `/app/code/Mike/etc/`. Within this `etc` folder, I have added a `di.xml` file containing the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="Mike\NewSelect\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
</config>
```

I then created a Module folder titled `NewSelect` and placed it in the `Mike` vendor folder:

`/app/code/Mike/NewSelect/`

I then just copied over the directory structure (without the containing files, except for Select.php) of the core Select class and placed it in the `NewSelect` module folder, resulting in the below:

```
app/
├── Mike/
│   ├── NewSelect/
│   │   ├── Block/
│   │   │   ├── Product/
│   │   │   │   ├── View/
│   │   │   │   │   ├── Options/
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── Type/
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── Select.php
│   │   ├── etc/
│   │   │   ├── di.xml
```

Within my new `Select` class `(app/code/Mike\NewSelect\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php)`, I have extended the core Select class with the following:

```
namespace Mike\NewSelect\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
{
 /**
     * Return html for control element
     *
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
etc etc...
```

In my `Mike/MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/catalog_product_view.xml` file, I have updated the calling block:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select_hamper.phtml"/>
```

and changed it to:

```
<block class="Mike\NewSelect\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We declare Dependency Injection

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="Mike\NewSelect\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
```

If someone ask for an instance of `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select`, we 'always' give them an instance of `Mike\NewSelect\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select`. Your custom class 'automatically' overrides the core class. So, we don't need to change:

```
<block class="Mike\NewSelect\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
```

Should keep `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select`